# SQL Server Authentication login between form

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm having some problems with my winform homework. I'm trying to create a  connection string like this:

```
string connection = @"Data Source=LAPTOP-R9MK201M;
Initial Catalog=QLBanvemaybay;
User ID="+textBoxUserID+"Password ="+textBoxPassword);
```

How can I call the connection above in `Form2`, `Form3`,....

Or still have some better ways to open connection between forms?

Comment: `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);`

Comment: I would create a Class say "HomeWorkDbService" which will manage connection, expose the function to manage the database.
I would create the class as Singleton.

Comment: @NirmalSubedi `I would create the class as Singleton` you wouldn't need an instance anyways, `static` would suffice as what state would you be maintaining?

Comment: But i don't know how to get textbox values from Login form @NirmalSubedi

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ can you make an example, please?

Comment: You can expose a function inside that class say "ConnectDb" that would take two string parameters username, password.

Comment: You need to pass the sql connection between forms so you do not need multiple connections.  See my two form project which creates instances of the form so you can pass data between forms : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: Do yourself a favor and DO NOT pass your sql connection around as suggested by @jdweng. That is certain way to decimate your connection pool in a hurry. A connection should be short lived. It is opened, used and destroyed quickly. That way the connection can be returned to the connection pool. If you keep a single connection open throughout the life of your application you will quickly run out of available connections in the pool when even a few people use your application.

Comment: @Sean Lange : How do you close the connection?  There is a connection pool in the c# application.

Comment: @jdweng not sure what you mean about a connection pool in the c# application. The connection pool is on the sql server. You should be wrapping connection (and any other objects inheriting IDisposable) with a USING statement.